# ASP.Net MVC deployment on IIS6, why do I get a 404 after enabling wildcard mapping?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

I have this ASP.NET MVC app that I've deployed on IIS6/Win2003 as a virtual directory, and I get a 404 error even after enabling wildcard mapping for aspnet_isapi.dll (as explained everywhere like http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/).

Why so? In fact, without enabling this, I get a 403 (forbidden), unless authorizing directory access (listing). But why do I get a 404 with mapping enabled? Is there something else to do to get it working? I have added Index.aspx in the Documents tab in IIS properties, but that doesn't change anything.

That's a very simple app, I have not modified the global.asax file at all. But I got it working on another server a few month ago without modifying it either, and I don't recall doing anything else.

Comment: Have you recycled the Application Pool that the site is running under? I've had this problem and recycling the app pool solved it for me.

Comment: Can you browse to static files in your virtual dir?

Comment: nope, that doesn't change a thing. I usually restart the app pool after every change to be sure.

Comment: In fact I can't, I get a 404 too.

Comment: Are the 404 error pages you're seeing ASP.NET 404 errors, or the default IIS 404s?

Comment: It's the default IIS 404 (http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/1797/404b.jpg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

ASP.Net 4 was prohibited in IIS. To correct this, go to Web Services Extensions and allow it. [Thanks to Brian Flynn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819844/asp-net-mvc-wildcard-mapping-iis-6-not-working/3060611#3060611) on this one.

Comment: I cant find any item under Web Services Extension...it says `there are no items to show in this view `